# Installed Ubuntu 11.10 alongside Windows 7 - getting grub> menu on boot

Tags: ubuntu, grub, multi-boot, ubuntu-11.10

So, I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 7 just now, on my girlfriend's laptop.  I used a USB stick and followed all the default options, choosing a partition size of 32GB for Ubuntu 11.10.

After installation completed, the machine rebooted and now all I'm left with is a command prompt like this:

**`grub>`**

I was expecting a boot menu rather than this, and I've idea how to proceed. Hoping someone can help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Command Line and Rescue Mode**
find in index no.8
grub> prompt: GRUB 2 loaded modules but was unable to find the grub.cfg file.
[Ubuntu Documents](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Reinstalling_GRUB2)
Was failing to get past the grub> prompt because I wasn't loading the initrd image. Did that and I was flying. Just ran update-grub once I got into Ubuntu proper.
from Ask Ubuntu [( a related Superuser Site  )](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6025/grub-always-fails-to-install-furthest-i-get-is-grub-prompt)
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing the Windows 7 partition was the only one present on your girlfriend's computer at the time of installation

Redo the installation procedure, only this time go to try Ubuntu.... once you have Ubuntu running from the LIVE CD, using Dash start GPARTED and delete all the partitions newly created by Ubuntu (basically all partitions except for the NFTS one) and resize your Windows partition in order to leave some space for Ubuntu (if you want to leave 32 GB for Ubuntu then leave that amount of space unallocated. though this should have already been done in the previous installation).

Now once you're done (the resizing might even take as long as an hour), go back to the Ubuntu installation procedure and choose install Ubuntu alongside windows, and it should all go smoothly!

Comment: Correct, single partition. Thanks, that seems straightforward enough. I'll give it a go.

Comment: Dang. Done all that, and now all I have is a `grub rescue>` prompt

Comment: right so ............... reboot once again from the live cd and try ubuntu..... open up a terminal prompt (you have to have a internet connection working for what you are about to do) and type this: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair Once it's done with the installation it will open up a graphical interface allowing you to customize (and in your case fix) your grub.
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair

Comment: I tried the boot repair program, but it didn't work. Still left with the grub rescue prompt. Grrr. I can ls (hd0,5)/ which shows the existence of a boot/ dir, but if I ls (hd0,5)/boot/ I get an error: out of disk message